# Sybase bcp: Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP data-file

Tags: sybase, sap-ase, bcp

I've got a couple of issues with bcp.
I'm trying to load data from a text file to Sybase ASE 16.0 . The DB is on my local machine (Win 7 64-bit).
I'm using this command:

`bcp dbname.owner.TO_INTS in "SomeInts.txt" -P password -S server -U sa  -f "bcp_tblTO_INTS.fmt" -e "bcp.errlog.txt"`

Here is the format file ("bcp_tblTO_INTS.fmt"):

`10.0
1
1 SYBINT4 0 5 "" 1 SEEMS_THIS_IS_IGNORED`

The target table has a single column, defined as an INT:
`CREATE TABLE owner.TO_INTS
  (
  FROM_INT INT NOT NULL
  )
  LOCK ALLPAGES
  ON 'default'
GO`

I have two problems.

1. bcp will only populate the target table if the data has just four characters in it (ie, values from 1000 to 9999). If I use values outside this range I get:

`Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP data-file.
bcp copy in failed`

2. The values are not being populated correctly:

Input value (in file) :  1000            Populated as (in Sybase):808464433

Input value (in file) :  9999            Populated as (in Sybase):960051513

The file encoding is ANSI. The EOL character is LF.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks
Dave.

Comment: Have you tried it without the Format file?  If it's only 1 column, then it shouldn't be needed.  Just use `-c` flag to denote a plain text input file.

Comment: Great, thanks. Using "-c" fixed everything (if I made the EOL character CRLF). If you want to add that as an answer then I will confirm it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your file is only one column, remove the format file and use the `-c` option instead.  This will BCP the file in *character* (plaintext) mode, and should resolve the issue.

As noted, you may need to change the EOL character to CRLF